# Multiprocessing Pool creating and killing processes indefinitely

Tags: python, multiprocessing

**EDIT**
This short code below triggers the same issue.

```
# top_level.py
import to_import

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This does not work
    t = to_import.Test()
    from pprint import pprint
    pprint(t.test())
```

```
#to_import.py
import multiprocessing as mp


def test_func(a, b):
    return a * b


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pairs = list()
        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(10):
                self.pairs.append((i, j))

    def test(self):
        pairs = tuple(self.pairs)
        with mp.Pool() as pool:
            results = pool.starmap(test_func, pairs)
        return results


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This works fine
    t = Test()
    from pprint import pprint
    pprint(t.test())
```

**END EDIT**

**DOUBLE EDIT**

Interestingly, this code works correctly when run from my command prompt, as opposed to how I'd been running it from within Spyder previously

**EDIT END**

I have a class Tin which stores a 3d surface as a series of points and triangles, and can generate a regular grid of points on that surface. The process of creating these points works fine when the multiprocessing flag is False.

However for very dense grids on large surfaces this process can be quite slow, so I implemented multiprocessing to speed it up.

```
# tin.py

from time import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def _points_from_face(points, grid_size):
    create 3d points within triangle on grid, uses other functions withinin this module

def _multiprocess_function(function, vals_gen, pool_size):
    with mp.Pool(processes=pool_size) as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(func=function,
                               iterable=vals_gen)
    return results

class Tin:
    def __init__(self, name, surface_dict):
        self.name = name
        self.points = surface_dict['Points']
        self.faces = dict(enumerate(surface_dict['Faces']))

    def generate_regular_grid(self, grid_size,
                              multiprocess=False,
                              pool_size=(mp.cpu_count()//2)):
        return_grid = dict()
        if pool_size < 1:
            multiprocess = False
        if multiprocess:
            faces_tuple = tuple(self.faces.values())
            vals_tuple = tuple((tuple(self.points[pid] for pid in face), grid_size)
                               for face in faces_tuple)
            results = _multiprocess_function(_points_from_face,
                                             vals_tuple,
                                             pool_size)
            for result in results:
                return_grid.update(result)
        else:
            for face in self.faces.values():
                points = tuple(self.points[pid] for pid in face)
                return_grid.update(_points_from_face(points, grid_size))
        return return_grid
```

When the Tin class and associated functions are in the same python file as the code calling them, the script works fine, the processes spin up, do their thing, and then close.

But when I import tin.py into another script and try to use multiprocessing, the program gets stuck creating and killing processes over and over without returning anything.

e.g.

```
# landxml.py

from time import time
from tin import Tin

def parse_landxml(xml_path: str, print_times=False) -> Tin:
    read xml file and return Tin contained within

if __name__ == '__main__':
    st = time()
    surface = parse_landxml('some_tin.xml',
                             print_times=True)
    grid = surface.generate_regular_grid(grid_size=2,
                                         print_times=True,
                                         multiprocess=True)
```

Do I need to keep everything in one long script or is there a way I can still use multiprocessing inside an imported script.

In addition landxml.py will be imported into another file itself, is this likely to cause the same problem again?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why the processes are "immediately dying off," but I do question whether multiprocessing will actually be of benefit to you in this scenario.  If all of the processes/threads are tasked with updating the same shared data structure, they'll wind up just being serialized ... basically, running slower than a single-threaded version because they really can't update the shared data structure meaningfully "at the same time."

Comment: @mike-robinson points from face returns a dict of x,y pairs to z values, which is the computationally intensive part. With multiprocessing to 6 cores a task which was taking 90 seconds was reduced to 50 seconds, so it definitely is benificial.